# How to add a custom subdomain to netlify if the domain is hosted in AWS, using Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, netlify

I have a domain `mydomain.com`, hosted in AWS. This domain is added as a hosted zone in AWS Route53, so that I can manage all subdomains from there. I have a netlify url like `https://my-netlify-address.netlify.app`. I would like to customize netlify url like `https://documentation.mydomain.com`.

I went through the documentation https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/configure-external-dns/#configure-a-subdomain and did everything as instructed. Under the hosted zone of `mydomain.com`, I created a `CNAME` record `documentation.mydomain.com` pointing to `my-netlify-address.netlify.app` and waited for 48 hours. Then I returned to `netlify` > `Domain management` > `Custom domains` > `Add custom domain`. I tried adding `documentation.mydomain.com`, and it showed error below;

> mydomain.com is already registered. If you registered this domain name
> through a different registrar, select Add domain to begin delegating
> it to Netlify.

Then I clicked `Add domain` button, but it again showed error like;

> custom_domain is owned by another account

Could someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Do not click the **Add domain** button. Delegating means moving the domain to Netlify's DNS servers. Verify that you created the correct CNAME at Route 53. Since you have not provided the actual domain name, we cannot test it and tell you what is wrong. There are Internet tools that can test your DNS resource records.

Comment: For a new resource record, the changes are almost instant. For an existing resource record (the CNAME you created), now you have to wait for the TTL to expire usually. That means create the record once correctly otherwise the caching kicks in which means waiting.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley I cross checked the CNAME. When I go to `https://documentation.mydomain.com/` using Firefox, it shows `Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue

Firefox detected a potential security threat and did not continue to documentation.mydomain.com because this website requires a secure connection.`. When I click `Advanced` button, it shows `Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN`

Comment: @JohnHanley the error is like `Websites prove their identity via certificates. Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for documentation.mydomain.com. The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.netlify.app, netlify.app
 
Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN`

Comment: Do not use a web browser to debug domain, certificate, and DNS problems. Did you install a valid certificate?

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley the certificate is residing in AWS and it works fine for `https://example.com` (instead of example, in my case `mydomain`)